# CSS Scrolling overflow content issue with absolute positioned items

Tags: css, responsive-design, css-position, absolute, react-virtualized

I have absolute positioned navigation items within a resizable container.

The problem is when you scrolled the overflow content horizontally, the child elements (they're absolute positioned because of they're being rendered as virtualized list so they must be absolute) don't keep their 100% width on scroll.

I'm attaching a codepen content that visualizes the issue below. Try to scroll right the overflow content and you'll see.

```css
body {
    font-family: system-ui;
    background: #eee;
}
.menu-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 150px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 2px solid #999;
    overflow: auto;
}
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #FFEDD8;
}
.menu-item {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0 10px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    height: 25px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border: 1px solid #76ABAE;
    background-color: #76ABAE;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-container">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="menu-item" style="top: 0">Home</div>
        <div class="menu-item" style="top: 30px">Movies</div>
        <div class="menu-item" style="top: 60px">Music</div>
        <div class="menu-item" style="top: 90px">Profile</div>
        <div class="menu-item" style="top: 120px">Contact Us</div>
        <div class="menu-item" style="top: 150px">There is some long content</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

See the Pen 
  [Resizable Left Menu](https://codepen.io/metehansenol/pen/XWQdRYE) by Metehan ([@metehansenol](https://codepen.io/metehansenol))
  on [CodePen](https://codepen.io).

---

Checked the solutions those associated with my question but they're not same. There is a dynamic resizable overflow content and absolute positioned virtual list items here so it's different.
It's about dynamic width of child elements not height.

I expect a CSS solution that the placeholders of child elements must be fulfill the scrollable area and all of items must have the same size with the most wider item.

---

Important reminder for those who are suggesting that stop positioning them as absolute, unfortunately it's not possible because the list is an output of virtualized list.

Check the output of this list if you need to know more;
[react-window](https://react-window.vercel.app)

Comment: First of all, you'll have to stop positioning these items absolute. Then make the `width: 100%` of the wrapper into a `min-width` _instead_, and add `display: inline-block`

Comment: As I mentioned in the question it's not possible to stop positioning them absolute because they're being rendered as virtualized list items. Check https://react-window.vercel.app/#/examples/list/fixed-size

Comment: Then you will probably have to involve additional JavaScript, to measure the necessary width, and apply it yourself.

Comment: "they're absolute positioned because they're being rendered as virtualized list so they must be absolute" ... this makes no sense to me. Any element can be styled as list without being absolutely positioned.

Comment: @BrettDonald have you checked the virtual scroll library that I pointed?